# What is the reasoning behind window and top property of window?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading the great [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter9.html#p1f737d59) 
and came across this:

```
window.window === window // true
```

#### And

```
window.top === window // true
```

#### And of course

```
window.top === window.top.top.top.window //true
```

This is all expected since the object is pointing to itself. And I also understand window holds all of the global JavaScript variables including itself but:

1. What is the use of this self pointer?
2. Why do we need top to point to same pointer
3. Uses for `window.top`?

Comment: `if ( window.self === window.top ) { not in a frame } else { in a frame }` take a look at [window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) and [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top)

Comment: note that this isn't always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**top**

`window.top` refers to the top-most window from a window nested in one or more layers of `<iframe>` sub-windows

**self (or window)**

From [the MDCN page for `window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self):

```
if (window.parent.frames[0] != window.self) {
   // this window is not the first frame in the list
}
```

> **window.self** is almost always used in comparisons like in the example above, which finds out if the current window is the first subframe in the parent frameset.